# How do you install Crystal Reports for .net 4.0 on a server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, .net-4.0, crystalreports

We made a project with Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0 using Crystal Reports.

But if we publish it on the server, it won't work. I remember that with Visual Studio 2008 you just downloaded an installer for the server, but I can't seem to find one for this version.

Or am I missing something?

The server is running Windows Server 2008.

Comment: my temporal fix is to instal visual studio 2010 and crystal reports 13.2 for visual studio 2010 on the server

Comment: 1. Have you install your CR 2010 on the server? 2. Have you try change it to local service? 3. Please dont forget to grant the permissons 4. If it still doesnt work, could you please advise the error message that you get? Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 1):

The re-distributable for the web server for the version which comes with Visual Studio 2010 can be found downloaded from SAP.

These links may go stale, but as of 17-Dec-2011:

http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/crystalreports-dotnet

The heading of the section is "Download Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010" under "Knowledge Center" and the link has text "Redist Installation (64 bit)"

The direct link is : http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_2.zip